# Unexpected token if - but a blank console?

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, google-chrome

The weirdest thing just happened to me:

I have not changed a single bit as far as I know, but out of the blue I get an error in the Chrome console, stating "unexpected token if", and strangely enough, it's in a different part of the script every time I call the page, AND the lines it refers to are blank!

The basic lay out of the page is a menu bar with buttons, each of which make an ajax call, in order to load a new .php in a designated div. Quite simple, worked like a charm for months.

Suddenly, when I press a specific one of these menu buttons (say button B), it loads the page, loads the elements, but doesn't fire a single line of javascript (jQuery), claiming to have that error, in either **index: line something** or sometimes in **jquery-1.9.1.min.js: line something else**.

I have gone through all my files and couldn't find a single fault, ran them through various syntax checkers and found no flaw, and am now simply out of ideas.

Anyone with experience in this matter, or any idea or handy method as to how to find out where the problem lies? Per request I can supply you with all kinds of reports, give you explain me how to obtain them. I'm not as experienced as I'd like to be, I'm afraid...

Thanks in advance, people!

Comment: I know you say that you did not change anything, but something must have changed. Could it be that jquery version got updated?

Comment: I know something must have, but it's so unexplicable.. No jQuery hasn't updated. I even replaced the file.

Comment: If only there were a way to get some sort of log, where I can see the last thing it properly executed..